# android push notification not removed when i swipe

Tags: android

android push notification not removed when i swipe

following is my code that i trying to implement push notification

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(icon)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setOngoing(true);


            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("Your Message", message);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("type", type);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("id", id);
            PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);

            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

can somebody help me to resolve these issue

Comment: thanks for your answer i am making changes to setOngoing(false)  i will let you know soon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.setOngoing(true);` should be false, or just remove this line, if you don't put the `.setOngoing(boolean)` it will be false, so you'll be able to swipe the notification.

More information [`setOnGoing`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean))

> Set whether this is an "ongoing" notification. Ongoing notifications cannot be dismissed by the user, so your application or service must take care of canceling them. They are typically used to indicate a background task that the user is actively engaged with (e.g., playing music) or is pending in some way and therefore occupying the device (e.g., a file download, sync operation, active network connection).

So your `mBuilder` should be like :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setOngoing(false); //or just remove it
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i am making changes to setOngoing(false)

Comment: wait a while i am checking now

Comment: It's okay, I created a sample to do that and if you remove the `setOngoing()` it will act like a false.

Comment: can i set it to false

Answer (score 1):

The `setOngoing` makes the notification not dismissible

```
.setOngoing(true);
```

Comment: i have already added .setOngoing(true) but why these happenig

Comment: You should remove it, or set it to `false`